# GET api for Parse Server with Where clause PHP

Tags: php, rest, curl, parse-server

I am having the following code to make a GET statement to the REST API of Parse server using PHP:

```
$query = json_encode(
array(
    'where' => array( 'userid' => "8728792347239" )
));
echo $query;
$ch = curl_init('https://*hidden*.herokuapp.com/parse/classes/computers?'.$query);
curl_setopt(
$ch, 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
array(
    'X-Parse-Application-Id: *hidden*',
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: *hidden*',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
)
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
{"code":102,"error":"Invalid parameter for query: {\"where\":{\"userid\":\"8728792347239\"}}"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

without having read the documentation, i bet it's supposed to be url-encoded, not json-encoded -OR- that the data is supposed to be in the POST body, not the URL query.

if guess #1 is correct, then your problem is that you're using `json_encode` instead of `http_build_query` eg

```
$query = http_build_query(
array(
    'where' => array( 'userid' => "8728792347239" )
));
```

if guess #2 is correct, then your problem is that you're adding the data to the url query instead of adding it to the request body, eg

```
$ch = curl_init('https://*hidden*.herokuapp.com/parse/classes/computers');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$query);
```